# how to look the value of thedata by lookup index?

Tags: text-processing, data

I have list of data array which I want to look the values by its index (id) and store to the index id from the data array. I can do it in spreadsheet VALUE LOOKUP function, but I still have lots of data to do this and I don't think spreadsheet function will be fast for huge data sets. I want you help me to let me know the script that can do it faster. My data array, index id and proposed out put is as follows.

data array

```
Id  Value 

1    10
2    20
3    30
4    40
6    60
8    80
10   100
```

index

```
Id 

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
```

Output will be

```
ID    Value
1  10
2  20
3  30
4  40
5  NULL
6  60
7  NULL
8  80
9  NULL 
10 100
11  NULL
12  NULL
13  NULL
```

Thank you for helping again.

Comment: this question is already solve http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88550/vlookup-function-in-unix

Comment: see output http://paste.ubuntu.com/6036949/

Comment: @RahulPatil,Thank you very much! It helps a lot and work perfect

Comment: @RahulPatil When you see a duplicate question, please flag it, select “it doesn't belong here, or it is a duplicate…”, then “duplicate of”, and enter the link to the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Try a nice mixture of awk and redis (an extremely quick open source NoSQL key-value store. See http://redis.io for details).

Use awk to parse your 2 files ("data_array.txt" and "index.txt") and to generate your redis commands.

Pipe the result of the 2 awk scripts into bash to execute them. That's it :-)

Step by step:

Generate your redis "SET" statements by parsing the data file starting with the third line like this:

```
awk '{if (FNR > 2) \
print "redis-cli SET VALUE:" $1 " \"" $2"\""}' data_array.txt
redis-cli SET VALUE:1 "10"
redis-cli SET VALUE:2 "20"
redis-cli SET VALUE:3 "30"
redis-cli SET VALUE:4 "40"
redis-cli SET VALUE:6 "60"
redis-cli SET VALUE:8 "80"
redis-cli SET VALUE:10 "100"
```

Pipe your redis "SET" statements into bash to execute them:

```
awk '{if (FNR > 2) \
print "redis-cli SET VALUE:" $1 " \"" $2"\""}' data_array.txt | bash
OK
OK
OK
OK
OK
OK
OK
```

Generate your redis "GET" statements by parsing the index file starting with the third line like this:

```
awk '{if (FNR > 2) print "printf \"" $1 " \" && redis-cli GET VALUE:" $1}' index.txt
echo 1 && redis-cli GET VALUE:1
echo 2 && redis-cli GET VALUE:2
echo 3 && redis-cli GET VALUE:3
echo 4 && redis-cli GET VALUE:4
echo 5 && redis-cli GET VALUE:5
echo 6 && redis-cli GET VALUE:6
echo 7 && redis-cli GET VALUE:7
echo 8 && redis-cli GET VALUE:8
echo 9 && redis-cli GET VALUE:9
echo 10 && redis-cli GET VALUE:10
echo 11 && redis-cli GET VALUE:11
echo 12 && redis-cli GET VALUE:12
echo 13 && redis-cli GET VALUE:13
```

Pipe your redis "GET" statements into bash to execute them:

```
awk '{if (FNR > 2) \
print "printf \"" $1 " \" && redis-cli GET VALUE:" $1}' index.txt |\
bash
1 "10"
2 "20"
3 "30"
4 "40"
5 (nil)
6 "60"
7 (nil)
8 "80"
9 (nil)
10 "100"
11 (nil)
12 (nil)
13 (nil)
```

Enjoy :-)

bernie

@Rahul Patil
@Gilles

I posted my answer here on purpose. Abraham's example data are nicely transparent so hopefully my answer is quickly to understand. The data in the [vlookup function in unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88550/vlookup-function-in-unix) example looked confusing to me...