# vlookup function in unix

Tags: text-processing

How to make something similar to Excel's vlookup function in Unix?

*excerpt from office website, [VLOOKUP](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx)*

> The V in VLOOKUP stands for vertical. Use VLOOKUP instead of HLOOKUP
>   when your comparison values are located in a column to the left of the
>   data that you want to find.
>
> Syntax VLOOKUP(lookup_value,table_array,col_index_num,range_lookup)
>
> Lookup_value    The value to search in the first column of the table
>   array. Lookup_value can be a value or a reference. If lookup_value is
>   smaller than the smallest value in the first column of table_array,
>   VLOOKUP returns the #N/A error value.
>
> Table_array    Two or more columns of data. Use a reference to a range
>   or a range name. The values in the first column of table_array are the
>   values searched by lookup_value. These values can be text, numbers, or
>   logical values. Uppercase and lowercase text are equivalent.
>
> Col_index_num    The column number in table_array from which the
>   matching value must be returned. A col_index_num of 1 returns the
>   value in the first column in table_array; a col_index_num of 2 returns
>   the value in the second column in table_array, and so on. If
>   col_index_num is:
>
> Less than 1, VLOOKUP returns the #VALUE! error value. Greater than the
>   number of columns in table_array, VLOOKUP returns the #REF! error
>   value.
>
> Range_lookup    A logical value that specifies whether you want
>   VLOOKUP to find an exact match or an approximate match:

#### File1:

```
1GR_P1:001PI
:040VG_L1
:001PO_L3
1JPI_P1:001PO_L1
1JPI_P1:001PO_L2
```

#### File2:

```
1JPI_P1:001PO_L1    1401UC
1JPI_P1:001PO_L2    1401UC
1HIK_P2:001ER       1402UC
1GR_P1:001PI        1402UC
```

#### Output-File3:

```
1GR_P1:001PI        1402UC
:040VG_L1       NA
:001PO_L3       NA
1JPI_P1:001PO_L1    1401UC
1JPI_P1:001PO_L2    1401UC
```

Answer (score 8):

There isn't a general function that will do a `vlookup` as a general function in Unix. Rather you're giving "bricks" from which you can build solutions to problems in a more customized approach. These "bricks" are tools such as `grep`, `awk`, and `sed` among others.

One of the tools, `awk` could be used as follows:

#### vlookup.awk

```
FNR==NR{
  a[$1]=$2
  next
}
{ if ($1 in a) {print $1, a[$1]} else {print $1, "NA"}  }
```

#### Example

```
$ awk -f vlookup.awk file2 file1
1GR_P1:001PI 1GR_P1:001PI
:040VG_L1 NA
:001PO_L3 NA
1JPI_P1:001PO_L1 1JPI_P1:001PO_L1
1JPI_P1:001PO_L2 1JPI_P1:001PO_L2
```

You can use the `column` command to cleanup the output:

```
$ awk -f vlookup.awk file2 file1 | column -t
1GR_P1:001PI      1GR_P1:001PI
:040VG_L1         NA
:001PO_L3         NA
1JPI_P1:001PO_L1  1JPI_P1:001PO_L1
1JPI_P1:001PO_L2  1JPI_P1:001PO_L2
```

#### Details

The above `awk` script takes all the content of file2 into an array which is indexed using the value as a key.

```
a[$1]=$1
```

Once `file2` has been read into array `a`, `file1` is then gone through a line at a time and a decision is made. If the value of the first column of `file1` is present in the array `a`, then the corresponding value in `file2`'s column 2 is printed along with `file1`'s column 1. If it isn't present then the "NA" message is printed.

Comment: Believe to meet the OP's requirement you need to change `a[$1]=$1` to `a[$1]=$2`

Comment: is `$1` column1 and `$2` column2? Or what is the difference between `a[$1]=$1` and `a[$1]=$2`

Comment: The `$1` and `$2` in `vlookup.awk` are columns but we're only setting `a[$1]==$2` when the FNR is equal to NR. See this example on SO for a better description of this method using `awk`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15065818/compare-files-with-awk.

Answer (score 2):

The POSIX `join(1)` command does something very similar to `VLOOKUP()`, with the caveat that *the input files must already be sorted on the columns to be joined*.

```
$ sort file1 > sfile1
$ sort file2 > sfile2
$ join -a1 sfile1 sfile2
1GR_P1:001PI 1402UC
1JPI_P1:001PO_L1 1401UC
1JPI_P1:001PO_L2 1401UC
:001PO_L3
:040VG_L1
```

Unfortunately, your example doesn't really illustrate how `join` works, since `file1` contains just one column.

To get exactly the output you want, you could write a simple script using associative arrays, using `awk` for example, as others have suggested.

Comment: TIL about `join` which is amazing

Answer (score 1):

For the specific data examples you have provided, the following should work. It loads field 2 from `File2` into an array indexed by field 1. `File1` is then looped through and array matches or `NA` are printed

```
awk 'NR == FNR{a[$1] = $2;next}; {print $1, $1 in a?a[$1]: "NA"}' File2 File1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for something which works from the command line have a look at `awk`. This is a VERY popular program used for all sorts of parsing operations. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK

Also, it's hard to mention parsing text in UNIX without mentioning `grep`. `grep` is used for regex matching text. While not needed for this particular application it will eventually come in handy if you're doing much text parsing.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep

Using `colrm` columns of text can be cut from a stream. This can be useful when you are having trouble isolating the text with `awk`.

`sed`is what you'll want to use if the text to parse is very long or if awk isn't able to easily accomplish what you want. [Sed on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed)

I'm sure I'm missing dozens but all you'll need for this example is `awk` so you're set.

Comment: I've added it for you krowe :)

Comment: @DravSloan - congrats o the 2k level!

Answer (score 0):

Try a mixture of awk and redis (an extremely quick open source NoSQL key-value store. See http://redis.io for details).

Use awk for parsing your 2 files to generate your redis commands.

Pipe the result of the 2 awk scripts into bash to execute them. That's it :-)

Step by step:

Generate your redis "SET" statements by parsing "File2" like this:

```
awk '{print "redis-cli SET KEY:" $1 " \"" $2"\""}' File2
redis-cli SET KEY:1JPI_P1:001PO_L1 "1401UC"
redis-cli SET KEY:1JPI_P1:001PO_L2 "1401UC"
redis-cli SET KEY:1HIK_P2:001ER "1402UC"
redis-cli SET KEY:1GR_P1:001PI "1402UC"
```

Pipe your generated redis "SET" statements into bash to execute them:

```
awk '{print "redis-cli SET KEY:" $1 " \"" $2"\""}' File2 |\
 bash
OK
OK
OK
OK
```

Generate your redis "GET" statements by parsing "File1" like this:

```
awk '{print "printf \"" $1 " \" && redis-cli GET KEY:" $1}' File1
printf "1GR_P1:001PI " && redis-cli GET KEY:1GR_P1:001PI
printf ":040VG_L1 " && redis-cli GET KEY::040VG_L1
printf ":001PO_L3 " && redis-cli GET KEY::001PO_L3
printf "1JPI_P1:001PO_L1 " && redis-cli GET KEY:1JPI_P1:001PO_L1
printf "1JPI_P1:001PO_L2 " && redis-cli GET KEY:1JPI_P1:001PO_L2
```

Now query redis by piping your redis "GET" statements generated above into bash:

```
awk '{print "printf \"" $1 " \" && redis-cli GET KEY:" $1}' File1 |\
 bash
1GR_P1:001PI "1402UC"
:040VG_L1 (nil)
:001PO_L3 (nil)
1JPI_P1:001PO_L1 "1401UC"
1JPI_P1:001PO_L2 "1401UC"
```

Beware that you need to escape double quotes in your strings with single backslashes to avoid redis import errors (see slm's answer at [How do I modify this Perl solution so that it will substitute embedded double quotes with single quotes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88482/how-do-i-modify-this-perl-solution-so-that-it-will-substitute-embedded-double-qu/88637#88637) ). You can also use single quotes to encapsulate your values for import into redis, if your values are containing a lot of double quotes.

HTH

bernie